# AWS face rekognition Bot on Raspberry Pi

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, robot

I am following a tutorial (https://github.com/just4give/raspi-dexter-lambda) that utilizes AWS rekognition on a raspberry pi to make a robot. I am having trouble figuring out how to create logs to see where the code is hanging up.

Here is the lambda function I need to debug:

```
'use strict';
const request = require('request');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region:'us-east-1'});
const rekognition = new AWS.Rekognition();
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
const sns = new AWS.SNS();
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

var config = {
  "awsRegion":"us-east-1",
  "s3Bucket":"raspi118528",
  "awsFaceCollection":"raspifacecollection"
}
module.exports.bot = (event, context, callback) => {
  try {
        // By default, treat the user request as coming from the America/New_York time zone.

        var intentName= event.currentIntent.name;
        console.log('intentName',intentName);

        switch (intentName) {
          case 'HelloIntent':
                  request(
                    {
                      url : process.env.URL_CAPTURE,
                      method:'POST',
                      headers : {
                      "Authorization" : "Basic " + new Buffer( "raspi:secret").toString("base64")
                    }
                    },
                    function (error, response, body) {

                        if(error){
                          callback(error);
                        }else{
                          body = JSON.parse(body);
                          console.log('body',body);
                          console.log('now',new Date());


                          if(body.status ==='matched'){
                            var hour = parseInt(moment().tz('America/New_York').format('h'));
                            console.log('hour',hour);
                            var content="";

                            if(hour >= 5 && hour<12){
                              content ="Good morning, "+ body.message+" ! Have a nice day!";
                            }else if(hour >=12 && hour <18){
                              content ="Good afternoon, "+ body.message+" ! Have a nice rest of the day!";
                            }else if(hour >=18 && hour < 21){
                              content ="Good evening, "+ body.message+" ! Talk to you soon!";
                            }else{
                              content ="Hi, "+ body.message+" ! It's been a long day! Good Night!";
                            }

                            const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
                                Bucket: config.s3Bucket,
                                Key: body.key,
                                Expires: 300
                            })

                            //console.log(url)

                            sns.publish({
                              Message: 'I just saw '+ body.message+' . See the image I captured. Link will expire in 5 minutes. ' + url,
                              TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:027378352884:raspiFaceTextMessage'
                            }, function (err, data) {
                              if(err){
                                console.log("error", err);
                              }else{
                                console.log('success',data);
                              }

                            });

                            callback(null,{
                                sessionAttributes: {key: body.key},
                                dialogAction: {
                                    type: 'Close',
                                    fulfillmentState:'Fulfilled',
                                    message:{
                                        contentType: 'PlainText',
                                        content: content
                                    }

                                },
                            })
                          }else if(body.status ==='error'){
                            callback(null,{
                                sessionAttributes: {key: body.key},
                                dialogAction: {
                                    type: 'Close',
                                    fulfillmentState:'Fulfilled',
                                    message:{
                                        contentType: 'PlainText',
                                        content: body.message
                                    }

                                },
                            })
                          }else if(body.status==='unmatched'){
                            callback(null,{
                                sessionAttributes: {key: body.key},
                                dialogAction: {
                                    type: 'ElicitIntent',
                                    //fulfillmentState:'Fulfilled',
                                    message:{
                                        contentType: 'PlainText',
                                        content: body.message
                                    }

                                },
                            })
                          }


                        }
                    }
                  );

              break;

          case 'NameIntent':
                    var name = event.currentIntent.slots.name;
                    var key = event.sessionAttributes.key;
                    var params = {
                        "CollectionId": config.awsFaceCollection,
                        "DetectionAttributes": [ "ALL" ],
                        "ExternalImageId": name,
                        "Image": {
                          "S3Object": {
                             "Bucket": config.s3Bucket,
                             "Name": key
                          }
                        }
                      }

                    rekognition.indexFaces(params, function(err, data) {
                        if (err) {
                          console.log(err, err.stack);
                        }else{
                          //console.log(data);

                          const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
                              Bucket: config.s3Bucket,
                              Key: key,
                              Expires: 300
                          })

                          //console.log(url)

                          sns.publish({
                            Message: 'I stored face of '+ name+' . See the image I loaded in my brain. Link will expire in 5 minutes. ' + url,
                            TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:027378352884:raspiFaceTextMessage'
                          }, function (err, data) {
                            if(err){
                              console.log("error", err);
                            }else{
                              console.log('success',data);
                            }

                          });

                          callback(null,{
                              sessionAttributes: {key: key},
                              dialogAction: {
                                  type: 'Close',
                                  fulfillmentState:'Fulfilled',
                                  message:{
                                      contentType: 'PlainText',
                                      content: "I stored your picture "+name+" . Have a nice day!"
                                  }

                              },
                          })
                        }

                    });

              break;

              case 'ClearAllFacesIntent':
                var params = {
                    "CollectionId": config.awsFaceCollection,
                    "MaxResults": 20
                }

                rekognition.listFaces(params, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                      else     {
                      console.log(data);
                      var faceIds=[];
                      data.Faces.forEach(function(face){
                        faceIds.push(face.FaceId);
                      })

                    if(faceIds.length>0){
                      var params = {
                      CollectionId: config.awsFaceCollection,
                      FaceIds: faceIds
                      };
                      rekognition.deleteFaces(params, function(err, data) {

                        if (err) {
                          callback(null,{
                              sessionAttributes: {key: key},
                              dialogAction: {
                                  type: 'Close',
                                  fulfillmentState:'Fulfilled',
                                  message:{
                                      contentType: 'PlainText',
                                      content: "Something went wrong! I could not delete faces!"
                                  }

                              },
                          })
                        }
                        else   {
                          callback(null,{
                              sessionAttributes: {key: key},
                              dialogAction: {
                                  type: 'Close',
                                  fulfillmentState:'Fulfilled',
                                  message:{
                                      contentType: 'PlainText',
                                      content: "I have deleted all the faces from memory!"
                                  }

                              },
                          })
                        }

                      });
                    }

                    }

                 });

                    break;

              case 'CloseIntent':
                    callback(null,{
                        sessionAttributes: {},
                        dialogAction: {
                            type: 'Close',
                            fulfillmentState:'Fulfilled',
                            message:{
                                contentType: 'PlainText',
                                content: "Good bye!"
                            }

                        },
                    })

              break;
          default:

        }




    } catch (err) {
        callback(err);
    }
};
```

This lambda is called upon by the bot in AWS. Whenever I use the NameIntent to say "My name is David" the server just asks me to repeat the statement.

Here is the logs in AWS console:
https://gyazo.com/ce778072ff659f727d0ccf227b466a3b

Please and Thank You for any help,
David

Answer (score 0):

You can log to cloudwatch using the regular `console.log()`